# Regex wildcard only after third letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex, that only allows wildcards after the third char in the string.

How would the regex look like?

Comment: You mean like `^abc.*`?

Comment: Basically, you want to check if a string starts with a specific text/pattern? Also, third *letter* != third *char*. What do you mean?

Comment: How is a "wildcard" defined in your requirements? Why regex and not `substring` + `includes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need a regex, that only allows wildcards after the third char in the string.

`^[^\*]{3}.*`

That regex will prevent a wildcard (*) from the first three characters, but also requires the string to be at least three characters long. You can add to the list of exclusions for other wildcard characters if needed.

`^[^\*\.]{3}.*` This will not allow `*` or `.` in the first three characters.

A simpler solution would be to check the if the first three characters for your wildcard instead of a regex.

Comment: I also dont want to accept space chararacter at the beginning. Could you help me with that too?

Comment: @farahm Stackoverflow is not a free code-writing service. The answer already contains the regex for "no asterisk" and for "no asterisk and no dot". It should be trivial to extend that to "no asterisk and no dot and no space"